# The requested URL was not found on this server while using lazy loading in angular

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, lazy-loading

after i use lazy loading in my angular projects, it works well in local host but the problem is : 
when i upload project on server if users write URL just like www.oceanweb.ir and then click on contact us button they will direct to contact us page "www.oceanweb.ir/contact-us" correctly but if they enter same URL (www.oceanweb.ir/contact-us) by them self and write it in address bar an error will occur

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

here is part of my routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LandingPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: "template",
    component: TemplateLayoutComponent,loadChildren: "./dashboard/template/template.module#TemplateModule"
  },
  {
    path: "contact-us",
    component: ContactUsLayoutComponent,loadChildren: "./dashboard/contact-us/contact-us.module#ContactUsModule"
  },
  {
    path: "education",
    component: EduLayoutComponent,loadChildren: "./dashboard/education/education.module#EducationModule"
  },
  {
    path: "recruitment",
    component: ReqLayoutComponent,loadChildren: "./dashboard/recruitment/recruitment.module#RecruitmentModule"
  }
];
```

Comment: have you import AppRoutingModule in app.module.ts.

Comment: yes dude i said i works well in local host but it just does not work when i upload project on server

Answer (score -2):

In your `app.module.ts` file add this line to provide array

```
providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

It's will solve your problem

Comment: it works ty. but how do i remove that # before any url address?